# caffe softmax with loss layer for semantic segmentation loss calculation

Tags: caffe, softmax, cross-entropy

The caffe documentation on the `softmax_loss_layer.hpp` file seems to be targeted towards classification tasks and not semantic segmentation. However, I have seen this layer being used for the latter.

1. What would be the dimensions of the input blobs and output blob in the case where you're classifying each pixel (semantic segmentation)?
2. More importantly, how are the equations for calculating the loss applied to these blobs? Like, in what form are the matrices/blobs arranged and the eventual "loss value" that's output, what is the equation for that?

Thank you.

edits:
I have referenced this page for understanding concepts of loss equation, just don't know how it's applied to the blobs, which axis, etc.: http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/

Here is the documentation from caffe:[image: caffe softmax with loss description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the input blobs should be of the form data `NxKxHxW` and label `Nx1XHxW` where each value in the label blob is an integer from `[0-K]`. I think there's an error in the caffe documentation where it doesn't consider the case for semantic segmentation, and I'm not sure what `K = CHW` means. The output blob is of the shape `1x1x1x1` which is the loss.

Secondly, the loss function is as follows, from `softmax_loss_layer.cpp`:

```
loss -= log(std::max(prob_data[i * dim + label_value * inner_num_ + j], Dtype(FLT_MIN)));
```

Breaking that line down (for semantic segmentation):

1. `std::max` is just to ensure there's no invalid input like `nan`
2. `prob_data` is the output from the softmax, as explained in the caffe tutorials, softmax loss layer can be decomposed into a softmax layer followed by multinomial logistic loss
3. `i * dim` specifies the `N`th image in your batch where the batch shape is like so `NxKxHxW` where K is the number of classes
4. `label_value * inner_num_` specifies the Kth image, because at this stage, each one of your classes have their own "image" of probabilities, so to speak
5. Finally, `j` is the index for each pixel

Basically, you want `prob_data[i * dim + label_value * inner_num_ + j]` for each pixel to be as close to 1 as possible. This means that the negative log of that will be close to 0. Here the `log` is to base `e`. And then you do the stochastic gradient descent for that loss.